# How can I skip lines with a specific character when saving a text file?

Tags: iphone, arrays, file, text

I would like to be able to get all of the lines of a text file that don't contain an >. I know first I would load the text file into an array of lines, but after that how would I quickly remove the lines that contain an >. (I am not going to just remove them from the text file for a reason that is irrelevant).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed blocks (iOS 4+), you could use this NSArray method

```
- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate
```

with the predicate returning YES when

```
[(NSString*)id rangeOfString:@">"].location != NSNotFound
```

then remove these strings from the original array by making it mutable and calling

```
- (void)removeObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes
```

with the indexSet you have just obtained.